# Rebus For Those Who Strive

Tags: rebus

Do you strive to do the impossible?  You might have heard someone say this!

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The rebus depicts a knot next to the word "shot" in an elongated font.

Hence, the answer is "not [knot] by [next to] a long shot."

Comment: Please hide your answer behind spoiler tags.

Comment: @IanMacDonald [According to meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1360/39), spoiler tags in answers are not required, and I prefer to not use them in my answers.

Comment: Would you care to explain why you prefer not to use them in your answers?

Comment: @MarkBannister IMHO, they're unnecessary clutter and only serve to make it more difficult for a user to navigate the site and actually view the posts. At the very least (again, this is simply my personal opinion), answers should still be... well, *answers* even if all the content inside of spoiler tags was removed.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I'm not speaking as a moderator but as a regular user here—I simply prefer not to use spoiler tags, and this is a personal style choice that I can choose to apply to my own answers. If this bothers you, you can install [a userscript such as this one](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1316/39) to hide the answers until you click a button.

Comment: No worries, fixed it for you

Comment: **If anyone wishes to reopen the discussion on when/whether spoiler tags are appropriate in answers, please do so on [Puzzling Meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/).** The way to make your point is not by editing this answer, but is rather by opening a discussion and providing new opinions on Meta.

Comment: The answer is right, but if it were me guessing, I would wonder why the long shot is next to a pretzel...   haha